# extern keyword with explicit template instantiation

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015

Consider a small toned down use case of my problem wherein I have a header as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#pragma once
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
template<typename T>
class FOO
{
public:
    void func() { std::cout << "Foo!"; };
};

extern template class __declspec(dllexport) FOO<int>;
using myfoo = FOO<int>;
#endif
```

and a source file as

```
#include "Header.h"

int main()
{
    myfoo f;
    f.func();
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this with VS 2015 (Update 3), I get following [warning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531392.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
warning C4910: 'FOO<int>': '__declspec(dllexport)' and 'extern' are incompatible on an explicit instantiation
```

MSDN page does not explain to me clearly why is it wrong to have `extern` and `dllexport` in explicit template declaration.

Can anybody please explain what is the rationale behind this ?

Comment: `__declspec(dllexport)` says: "this is the definition of an object or function, which should be exported from a DLL". `extern` says: "this is merely a declaration; the definition is somewhere else". The two make no sense together. You likely want `template class __declspec(dllexport) FOO<int>;`, and you want it in a source file, not in a header.

Comment: If you wish a dll, use extern "C" for classes and funcs, and make a macro for switching between __declspec(dllimport) for your .cpp-file and __declspec(dllexport) for dll header.

Comment: I want to export an explicit template instantiation but I also want to avoid the code bloat which I read [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#extern-templates). May be I am mixing up two things ? Am I ?

Comment: You can declare it with `extern` in a header file, and define with `__declspec(dllexport)` in a source file. You can't do both on the same line though.